# Why is the pressure pulse bigger after exercise?

Tags: cardiology, hematology, exercise

Right after exercise, is the amplitude of the pulse smaller or bigger than resting period? And why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that pulse pressure increases after exercise. As I understand it,

- Systolic pressure is simply resistance against the pressure wave of the ejected blood. Since the stroke volume is increased in exercise to deliver more blood, systolic pressure will be definitely be increased.
- During diastole, the major resistance to flow is due to peripheral resistance (major arteries now assist flow by releasing stored energy), and this is reduced in exercise due to vasodilation. Although there is more flow, since the resistance is markedly reduced, diastolic pressure may drop.

Hence, pulse pressure should increase.

Comment: It'd be important to note that during exercise, there is systemic vasoconstriction but vasodilation in the vessels to the muscles. This sums up to a net vasodilation (due to the enormous bulk of musculature), resulting in a fall in net peripheral resistance and hence, the diastolic pressure.